# "This value should not be blank. " when I enter an existing username

Tags: symfony, symfony-2.1, fosuserbundle

I'm trying to create a form where you can select a user (this example is a new article where the user can write (text) a username). When I write an existing username I have the error:

> This value should not be blank.

When it's not an existing username I get:

> This value is not valid.

**`ArticleType`**

```php
->add('author', 'fos_user_username')
```

OR (I've the same problem with a custom model transformer)

```php
->add(
   $builder->create('author', 'text')->addModelTransformer($transformer)
);
```

**`Article`** entity with a linked author

```php
/**
 * @Assert\NotBlank()
 * @Assert\Type(type="Acme\UserBundle\Entity\User", groups={"default", "registration", "profile"})
 * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Acme\UserBundle\Entity\User")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
private $author;
```

Comment: Nothing to do with your question, but shouldn´t the relationship be ManyToOne? Probably one user can be the author of many articles